# Represent LinkedList in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, data-structures, linked-list, simplecursoradapter

I want to represent a playlist in my Android app. if the playlist is empty my items are just shown by date. If the playlist contains a few items then the playlist should be shown in order, followed by the remaining items (still by date).

However, I'm not sure how to model this efficiently. How could I structure my database in suck a way so it becomes easy to insert items (to any position) in the playlist, and still select them in a fast (and reasonable easy) way.

**Example** I have a list with the items A,B,C,D,E,F,G. At first the items are shown in order:

```
  A,B,C,D,E,F,G
```

The user now adds F and the D to his playlist. The items should now be show in this order:

```
 F,D,A,B,C,E,G
```

Comment: select * from items_table

Answer (score -1):

> How could I structure my database in such a way so it becomes easy to
>   insert items (to any position)

Create classic **`heap table`** which provides quick inserting - *"insert on the first position you can insert."*

> and still select them in a fast (and reasonable easy) way.

So most likely you need to create [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index). Indexes are created on columns which are most often occur behind **`where clause`**. By creating index is also **`b+ tree`** created so you should be careful when you want to create any index.

Also there are more ways but it strongly depends on datasource type for example Oracle provides many types of tables with various advantages and disadvantages.

Also specific approach you will choose depends also on database - requirements on db, the average number of records in table(s) and so on.

Comment: That sounds right, but how would you create a select statement getting these items in the right order? Without any special modules or things Android doesn't support.

Comment: So sometimes is necessary to make "compromises". That what you just described you are right, its not possible to make it in db. So my first idea is make classic ordered select but if you have some items in playlist - so get some specific data(id for example) from them to be able to perform next query that will select items which are in playlist(save them into classic List) and second query that will select other items from db(items will be saved into List from previous select).

Answer (score -1):

If you you want to order items based on some sort of time stamp (for example you want the newest to appear first), then just add a timestamp column to your table, such as creation date or update date/time. Then, when querying the table, use that to sort.

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMS_TABLE
ORDER BY CREATION_DATETIME DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this solution. I've added an extra column in table say "sequence" which will have order number in which records to be fetched.. while fetching order the table by "sequence" and you will get desired order.

But inserting a row or deleting a row requires lot of updates on sequence.